# Find whole number only in string

Tags: c#, linq

Looking to get the first whole number in a string or the number before a word in a string.

For Example

```
string input = "hello 123.45 789 coins";
```

To ignore the 123.45 and only convert the 789 to a int.

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: split by space and then iterate. I don't see how this requires complex thinking.

Comment: a regex for christmas... : `\b\d+\b`

Comment: I'd scan the line and start memorizing the read characters if I encounter a digit. Then, if something else than a dot follows this series of digits, you've found a candidate. If a dot follows the number, it can still be the end of a sentence. Hence if a non-digit (most likely a blank) follows the dot, the number found so far still qualifies. You might want to think about values like `1e6`.

Comment: `123` could be the first whole number, at the end of a sentence (followed by a dot) `45 789` could be a whole number as well, in french notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some regex would suffice, or somthing simple like:

```cs
var valueString = "hello 123.45 789 coins REE";

var words = valueString.Split(' ');

for (var index = 0; index < words.Length-1 ; index++) // words.Length-1 so the last item is skipped 
{
    var word = words[index];
    var nextWord  = words[index+1]; // optionally check if the next word is an int or not?

    if (int.TryParse(word, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var valueInt))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(valueInt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex expression

```
\d+(?![0-9.])
```

Explanation

- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
- Negative Look ahead `(?![0-9.])`. Regex does not match Match a single character present in the list below
- `[0-9.]` 0-9 matches a single character in the range between 0 and 9,
- `.` matches the character(.) with index 4610 literally (case sensitive)
- m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ to match the begin/end of each line

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I have formatted your question, yet I didn't understand all of it ("m modifier"? your code does not include it). BTW, in the question comments there is a Regex that looks probably better, you may want to check it and if you use it give credit to Mong Zhu.